# CF - Read files from host desktop

Tags: c#, compact-framework, file-sharing

I am writing sample app for win mobile devices using Compact framework.
App should read files (pictures, .jpg) from host desktop.
Is there sample or something build in for task like this?
In what kind of relation are device and host when device connecting to workstation using ActiveSync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an ActiveSync connection you have an RNDIS network between the two.  This means you can do an ethernet socket between them for transferring data, so any example of passing data from two devices (i.e. even PC-to-PC) over a network becomes valid.

There is no way for the device to initiate a file transfer (except from something like FTP, a web service, etc).  ActiveSync is 100% PC-initiated, so using RAPI is also PC-initiated.